# LUIS entities returned in lower case

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have [LUIS](http://luis.ai) helping me out extracting intents and/or entities from the text I'm sending. The problem is, when it detects an entity it sends it back in lower case.

Is there a way to configure or work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently by design from the LUIS team.  There are some suggestions in how to work around this though in this github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/963